# (Windows) PutStrLn stops working when inserting code from library

Tags: haskell, ghc, z3, ffi

I've noticed some really strange behaviour:

I'm trying to get the [haskell z3 bindings](https://github.com/IagoAbal/haskell-z3) to work on windows. But if I insert code from the library into the `Main` module `putStrLn` stops working. How can that be?

## The Setup

1. I used the precompiled x64 binary of the z3 solver ([z3.4.8.4](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/tag/z3-4.8.4)) for windows (and put it in `C:\mylibs\z3-4.8.4_x64`).
2. Then I created a stack project `haskellZ3Test`

The relevant parts from `package.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- z3 <= 408.0
```

The relevant parts from `stack.yaml`:

```
resolver: lts-13.28

packages:
- . 
- location:
    git: https://github.com/IagoAbal/haskell-z3.git
    commit: b10e09b8a809fb5bbbb1ef86aeb62109ece99cae
  extra-dep: true

extra-include-dirs:
- "C:\\mylibs\\z3-4.8.4_x64\\include"
extra-lib-dirs:
- "C:\\mylibs\\z3-4.8.4_x64\\bin"
```

## The Problem

Here is `Main` version 1:

```
module Main where

import Z3.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello world"
```

If I `stack build` and then `stack exec haskellZ3Test-exe` I get `hello world` on the command line as expected.

However - here is `Main` version 2:

```
module Main where

import Z3.Monad

ast :: Z3 AST
ast = do
  a <- mkFreshBoolVar "A"
  b <- mkFreshBoolVar "B"
  mkImplies a b

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello world"
```

If I `stack build` and then `stack exec haskellZ3Test-exe` now I get nothing ...

Honestly I'm pretty puzzled - compiling and linking seems to work fine. 
Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a bug in that library. Perhaps opening an issue would help.

Comment: You get nothing: As in it just hangs, or quits without printing anything?

Comment: And if it terminates what is the exit code?

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the dynamic loading or other aspect before even getting to the `_start` routine.  If you load it up with a debugger things might become clearer.  Perhaps the z3 library is corrupt.

Comment: @alias It just quits without printing anything

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Thanks for the hint! I will check the exit code - I'm not too familiar with Haskell FFI but I will try debug it.

Comment: Is `libz3.dll` in your `PATH`? Various systems give various degrees of useless error message if they can't load a DLL; it's quite possible that Haskell just aborts without any error message in this case (but I've never tried it).